# Problem with virtual host on zend server (CE)

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, virtualhost

I am trying to install a virtual host on zend server ce but get the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

This is how my virtual host configuration looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName stage5local
 DocumentRoot K:/stage5/public_html
 <Directory K:/stage5/public_html>
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I uncommented this line in my httpd.conf:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I have added stage5local to my host file. 
After i did all this I restarted my apache server.

I am running on windows XP.

Any idea's?

Can it be because k:/stage5 is not within my webroot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can the webserver read `K:\stage5\public_html`?

Assuming K is NTFS, you can check by:

- Disable simple file sharing by clicking [here](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9645380)
- Right click on the folder `K:\stage5\public_html`
- Go to the **Security** tab
- Give the username `ZEND SERVER` access to read